# Python VK API TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, объекты

Иногда случается это ошибка с разными пользователями не всеми почему так?

```
if (cmd.lower().startswith("перевод ")):
        try:
            c, i, a = cmd.lower().split(" ")
            a = int(a)                
        except ValueError:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

            return await msg.answer(" .азино перевод [ид] [сумма] - перевести пользователю сумму.")   

        except Exception:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()

            self.current.remove(msg)
            return await msg.answer("Произошла ошибка.")       

        target = await parse_user_id(msg, custom_text=i)

        delta = Decimal(Decimal("1") * Decimal(a))

        if not target or target < 0:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

            return await msg.answer(" Я не нашел такого пользователя, попробуй написать подругому, имя/ид/ссылка/упоминание.")       

        if target == msg.user_id:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

            return await msg.answer(" Вы не можете переводить деньги самому себе.")

        if delta < 5:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(f" Минимальная сумма перевода: {round(self.min_bet, 2)}$")

        pp, _ = await self.pwmanager.get_or_create(self.player, user_id=msg.user_id)    

        p, _ = await self.pwmanager.get_or_create(self.player, user_id=target)    

        if delta > pp.bank:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(f" У вас не хватает средств!\n Ваш банк счет: {round(pp.bank, 2)}$")    

        users = await self.api.users.get(user_ids=i)
        user = users[0]



async def parse_user_id(msg, can_be_argument=True, argument_ind=-1, custom_text=None):
for m in traverse(await msg.get_full_forwarded()):
    if m.user_id and m.true_user_id != msg.user_id:
        return m.true_user_id

if not can_be_argument:
    return None

if custom_text is None:
    original_text = msg.text
else:
    original_text = custom_text

text = original_text.split(" ")[argument_ind]

if text.isdigit():
    return int(text)

if text.startswith("https://vk.com/"):
    text = text[15:]

if text[:3] == "[id":
    puid = text[3:].split("|")[0]

    if puid.isdigit() and "]" in text[3:]:
        return int(puid)

if "__chat_data" in msg.meta:
    if argument_ind == -1:
        targets = [original_text.split(" ")[-1].strip().lower()]
    else:
        targets = [i.strip().lower() for i in original_text.split(" ")[argument_ind: argument_ind + 2]]

    max_match, user_id = 0, None
    for u in msg.meta["__chat_data"].users:
        if u.get("screen_name") == text:
            return u["id"]

        matches = 0
        if u.get("first_name", "").strip().lower() in targets:
            matches += 1
        if u.get("last_name", "").strip().lower() in targets:
            matches += 1
        if u.get("nickname", "").strip().lower() in targets:
            matches += 1

        if matches > 0:
            if matches > max_match:
                max_match = matches
                user_id = u["id"]

            elif matches == max_match:
                user_id = None
                break

    if user_id is not None:
        return user_id

tuid = await msg.api.utils.resolveScreenName(screen_name=text)

if tuid and isinstance(tuid, dict):
    return tuid.get("object_id")

return None


2018-03-27T17:00:18.656273+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/plugins/games/azino.py", line 1527, in process_message
```

2018-03-27T17:00:18.656276+00:00 app[worker.1]:     user = users[0]
2018-03-27T17:00:18.656282+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Нужен полный стек с ошибкой, а то можно угадывать где именно ошибка произошла. Подскажу, что ошибка возникла из-за квадратных скобок у bool, пример воспроизведения ошибки `True[0]`

Comment: Понял ошибку, благодарю

Comment: если вы думаете что кто-то ещё с подобной ошибкой может столкнуться и найти ваш вопрос, то можете опубликовать ваше понимание ошибки в виде ответа. См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer